# マルチステージビルドしたvueアプリケーションコンテナがAPIコンテナと疎通できない

Tags: docker, vue.js

#### 実現したいこと

nginxのfrontendとSpring bootで作ったbackendを疎通させたい。

#### 前提

VPS上にdockerをインストールし以下の構成を作成しwebアプリケーションをデプロイしています。

- frontend：vue
- backend：Spring boot
- DB：Mysql

※frontendとbackendの疎通は開発環境により確認済み
※backendとDBの疎通も確認済み

フォルダ構成は以下のようになっています。

```
Workspace
├─docker-compose-verifi.yml
├─.vscode
├─infra
│  ├─spring
│  │  └─Dockerfile.verifi
│  └─vue
│     ├─Dockerfile.verifi
│     └─nginx-verifi.conf
├─spring_workspace(backendコンテナにvindマウント)
└─vue_workspace(frontendコンテナにvindマウント)
    └─front_app
        ├─node_modules
        ├─public
        └─src
```

##### 環境構築フロー

0. docker-compose -f docker-compose-verifi.ymlを実行
1. [frontend]-node.js環境でビルド後productionステージでビルド結果を配置
2. [backend]-builderステージでSpring bootプロジェクトをビルド後openjdk環境にビルド結果を配置

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

マルチステージビルドを用いてnode.js環境でビルドしたjsファイルをnginxに配置して配信しようとしています。
node.js環境でyarn run serveを実施した場合は正常に動作しますが、node.js環境でビルドしたファイルをnginxのwebrootの位置に配置するとバックエンドとの通信ができなくなってしまします。
ブラウザのコンソールには何も表示されておらず、バックエンドのSpring bootのログにも何も表示されていないのでビルド時に正しくjsのパスがマッピングされておらず、APIRequestを実行できていないと予想しvue.config.jsにpublicPathを追加して再実行しても変化ありませんでした。

Webアプリケーションの開発の知識が疎いため原因と解決法をご教授いただけると幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

#### 該当のソースコード

docker-compose-verifi.yml

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  
  backend:
    container_name: spring-container
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./infra/spring/Dockerfile.verifi #backend構築用
      args:
        HOST_ENV: http://<ホストIPアドレス>:9001　#通信を許可するIPアドレス
        DATABASE_URL: <DBサーバーIPアドレス> #DBのIPアドレス
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    expose:
      - 8080
    working_dir: /srv
    tty: true
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: <DBサーバーIPアドレス>
      HOST_ENV: http://<ホストIPアドレス>:9001
    
  frontend:
    container_name: vue-container
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./infra/vue/Dockerfile.verifi
    ports:
      - 9001:80
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - node_modules:/app/node_modules
  
    environment:
      VUE_APP_BASE_URL: http://<ホストIPアドレス>:8080
      VUE_APP_BROWSER_BASE_URL: http://<ホストIPアドレス>:8080
    
volumes:
  node_modules:
  deploy_modules:
```

Dockerfile.verifi(backend環境構築用)

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk AS builder

WORKDIR /srv/app
ARG HOST_ENV
ENV HOST_ENV=${HOST_ENV}
ARG DATABASE_URL
ENV DATABASE_URL=${DATABASE_URL}
COPY ./spring_workspace/app /srv/app
COPY ./spring_workspace/app/pom.xml /srv/ap
RUN apt update
RUN apt-get -y install maven
RUN mvn package

FROM openjdk:17-alpine
COPY --from=builder /srv/app/target/*.jar /app/app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app/app.jar"]
```

Dockerfile.verifi(frontend環境構築用)

```
FROM node:20-alpine3.17 as build-stage

# ENV NODE_ENV production

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./vue_workspace/front_app /app
COPY ./vue_workspace/front_app/package*.json ./
COPY ./vue_workspace/front_app/yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install
COPY ./vue_workspace/front_app/ /app/
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/nginx/html && \
    yarn run build


#マルチステージビルド：build-stageでビルドした/usr/share/nginx/html以下をnginxのwebroot以下に配置する。
FROM nginx:1.17.10-alpine as production-stage

RUN mkdir /app
COPY --from=build-stage /usr/share/nginx/html /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./infra/vue/nginx-verifi.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

nginxの設定ファイル

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  <hostのIPアドレス>;
  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }

  location ~ ^/css/*\.(css)$ {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

  }
  location ~ ^/[^/]*\.(css)$ {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/css;

  }

  location ~ ^/js/*\.(js)$ {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

  }
  location ~ ^/[^/]*\.(js)$ {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/js;

  }

  location ~ ^/img/*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|woff|woff2|ttf)$ {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

  }
  location ~ ^/[^/]*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|woff|woff2|ttf)$ {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/img;

  }

  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
  error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
}
```

#### 試したこと

①ビルドパスの変更
ボタンの挙動や画面遷移の動作、backへのAPIRequestの動作が想定通りでないことから、画面とjsが結びついていないと考えビルド先のフォルダ構成をnginxと同じ構成に設定しました。
また、ビルド時に相対パス設定に変更しましたが状況変わらずwebコンソールにエラー表示もなく期待通りの動作になりませんでした。

vue.config.js

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
    transpileDependencies: true,
    devServer:{
        port: 80,
        client:{
            webSocketURL: 'ws://0.0.0.0:80/ws',
        },
        allowedHosts: 'all',
    },
    outputDir: '/usr/share/nginx/html',
    publicPath: './'

})
```

②開発環境との差分確認
開発環境ではfrontend起動のDockerfileをproductnステージがない状態のものを使用しています。

Dockerfile.dev(frontend環境構築用)

```
FROM node:20-alpine3.17 as build-stage

ENV NODE_ENV production

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./vue_workspace/front_app /app
COPY ./vue_workspace/front_app/package*.json ./
COPY ./vue_workspace/front_app/yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install
COPY ./vue_workspace/front_app/ /app/
```

こちらを用いてfrontendを構築後、コンテナ内にてyarn run serveを実行すると正常に動作しています。
開発環境と検証環境の違いはfrontendの実行環境がnode.jsかnginxかの違いのみですので
②の結果から

1. nginxの設定ファイルに不備がある
2. ビルド方法に不備がある

のどちらかだと考えていますが、見直してみても不具合箇所が特定できませんでした。